# React - TypeScript - Ant Design Form - Cannot pass props to wrapped components

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a component wrapping an ant design form like so:

```
export interface IMyProps {
    onSubmit: () => void,
    anInput: React.ReactNode
}

export class MyForm extends React.Component<IMyProps> {

    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Form onSubmit={this.props.onSubmit}>
                {this.props.anInput}
            </Form>
        )
    }
}
```

I wanted to be able to pass any ReactNode to my form structure and a function to handle the submiting of the form.

So I also have this component that defines the component passed to MyForm:

```
export interface IDecoratorProps extends FormComponentProps {
    onSubmit: () => void,
    value: string
}

class MyDecoratedForm extends React.Component<IDecoratorProps> {

    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <MyForm
                    onSubmit={this.props.onSubmit}
                    anInput={
                        <Form.Item
                            label={"label"}
                            hasFeedback>
                            {
                                this.props.form.getFieldDecorator(
                                    "label",
                                    {
                                        rules: [{required: true, message: 'This is required'}]
                                    }
                                )
                                (
                                    < Input size="large" type="text" value={this.props.value}/>
                                )
                            }
                        </Form.Item>
                    }/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export const MyFormDecorator = Form.create<IDecoratorProps>()(MyDecoratedForm);
```

And finally I have the Page component that is supposed to pass in the value props and onSubmit props.

Something like this:

```
...
render() {
    <MyFormDecorator value={this.state.value} onSubmit={() => {}}/>
}
```

My problem is that I have a

> TS2339: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes &
>   IntrinsicClassAttributes, ComponentState>>
>   & ...